# Fastest way to split character vectors into new rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, split

I wasn't sure how to word this correctly while searching, so sorry if this has a simple answer.

I have 58 dataframes with ~25,000 rows each that I am getting from .csv's. They look something like this:

```
Probe.Id     Gene.Id             Score.d
1418126_at   6352                28.52578
145119_a_at  2192                24.87866
1423477_at   NA                  24.43532
1434193_at   100506144///9204    6.22395
```

Ideally I want to split the Ids at the "///"s and get them on new rows. Like so:

```
Probe.Id     Gene.Id             Score.d
1418126_at   6352                28.52578
145119_a_at  2192                24.87866
1423477_at   NA                  24.43532
1434193_at   100506144           6.22395
1434193_at   9204                6.22395
```

Using strsplit allows me to get Gene.Id as a list of character vectors, but once I have that I'm not sure what the most effective way is to get each of the individual ids on their own row with the correct values from the other columns. Ideally I don't want to just be looping through 25,000 rows.

If anyone knows the right way to do this I'd super appreciate it.

**EDIT:** I should've added that there's a complicating factor in that there are rows which have ids like so:

```
333932///126961///653604///8350///8354///8355///8356///8968///8352///8358///835‌​1///8353///8357"
```

and I have no idea what the maximum number of ids in a row is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** New solution after OP's comment. Very straightforward using `data.table`:

```
df <- structure(list(Probe.Id = c("1418126_at", "145119_a_at", "1423477_at", 
        "1434193_at", "100_at"), Gene.Id = c("6352", "2192", NA, 
        "100506144///9204", "100506144///100506146///100506148///100506150"), 
         Score.d = c(28.52578, 24.87866, 24.43532, 6.22395, 6.22395)), 
        .Names = c("Probe.Id", "Gene.Id", "Score.d"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), 
        class = "data.frame")

require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt.out <- dt[, list(Probe.Id = Probe.Id, 
          Gene.Id = unlist(strsplit(Gene.Id, "///")), 
          Score.d = Score.d), by=1:nrow(dt)]

> dt.out

#    nrow    Probe.Id   Gene.Id  Score.d
# 1:    1  1418126_at      6352 28.52578
# 2:    2 145119_a_at      2192 24.87866
# 3:    3  1423477_at        NA 24.43532
# 4:    4  1434193_at 100506144  6.22395
# 5:    4  1434193_at      9204  6.22395
# 6:    5      100_at 100506144  6.22395
# 7:    5      100_at 100506146  6.22395
# 8:    5      100_at 100506148  6.22395
# 9:    5      100_at 100506150  6.22395
```

You could add `fixed = TRUE` to the `strsplit` expression to speedup further, if `///` is a fixed pattern.

**Alternative** Again using `data.table`. Taking into consideration that `strsplit` is a vectorised operation and that running it on the whole of `Gene.Id` column would be much faster than running it thro' 1 row at a time (even though `data.table` runs thro' very fast, you could get more speedup by splitting the previous code into 2 steps:

```
# first split using strsplit (data.table can hold list in its columns!!)
dt[, Gene.Id_split := strsplit(dt$Gene.Id, "///", fixed=TRUE)]
# then just unlist them
dt.2 <- dt[, list(Probe.Id = Probe.Id, 
                  Gene.Id = unlist(Gene.Id_split), 
                  Score.d = Score.d), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

I just replicated the `data.table` shown in this example many times until I got `295245` rows. And then I ran a benchmark using `rbenchmark`:

```
# first function
DT1 <- function() {
    dt.1 <- dt[, list(Probe.Id = Probe.Id, 
             Gene.Id = unlist(strsplit(Gene.Id, "///", fixed = TRUE)), 
             Score.d = Score.d), by=1:nrow(dt)]
}

# expected to be faster function
DT2 <- function() {
    dt[, Gene.Id_split := strsplit(dt$Gene.Id, "///", fixed=TRUE)]
    # then just unlist them
    dt.2 <- dt[, list(Probe.Id = Probe.Id, Gene.Id = unlist(Gene.Id_split), Score.d = Score.d), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
}

require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(DT1(), DT2(), replications=10, order="elapsed")

#    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 2 DT2()           10  15.708    1.000    14.390    0.391
# 1 DT1()           10  24.957    1.589    23.723    0.436
```

For this example, you get about 1.6 times faster. But this depends on the number of entries with `///`. Hope this helps.

**OLD solution:** (for continuity)

One way is to: 1) `find the positions` where this `///` occurs, 2) `extract`, 3) `duplicate`, 4) `sub` and 5) `combine` them.

```
df <- structure(list(Probe.Id = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), 
         .Label = c("1418126_at", "1423477_at", "1434193_at", "145119_a_at"), 
         class = "factor"), Gene.Id = structure(c(3L, 2L, NA, 1L), 
         .Label = c("100506144///9204", "2192", "6352"), class = "factor"), 
         Score.d = c(28.52578, 24.87866, 24.43532, 6.22395)), 
         .Names = c("Probe.Id", "Gene.Id", "Score.d"), 
         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

# 1) get the positions of "///"
idx <- grepl("[/]{3}", df$Gene.Id)

# 2) create 3 data.frames
df1 <- df[!idx, ] # don't touch this.
df2 <- df[idx, ] # we need to work on this

# 3) duplicate
df3 <- df2 # duplicate it.

4) sub    
df2$Gene.Id <- sub("[/]{3}.*$", "", df2$Gene.Id) # replace the end
df3$Gene.Id <- sub("^.*[/]{3}", "", df3$Gene.Id) # replace the beginning

# 5) combine/put them back
df.out <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)

# if necessary sort them here.
```

Comment: Thanks, I should've added that there's a complicating factor in that there are rows which have ids like "333932///126961///653604///8350///8354///8355///8356///8968///8352///8358///8351///8353///8357" and I have no idea what the maximum number of ids in a row is.

Comment: Thanks! I super appreciate this!

Comment: @user2019933, do be sure to "upvote" answers that you find helpful and "accept" answers which solve your problem.

Comment: Right! Sorry, new to this.

Answer (score 2):

here a solution using `strsplit` and `merge`

```
dat <- read.table(text ='Probe.Id     Gene.Id             Score.d
1418126_at   6352                28.52578
145119_a_at  2192                24.87866
1423477_at   NA                  24.43532
1434193_at   100506144///9204    6.22395',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
dat1 <- dat
xx <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(dat$Gene.Id,split='///'))
dat[which(xx[,1]!=xx[,2]),2]  <- xx[which(xx[,1]!=xx[,2]),1]
dat1[which(xx[,1]!=xx[,2]),2]  <- xx[which(xx[,1]!=xx[,2]),2]
  merge(dat,dat1,all.y=T,all.x=T)
     Probe.Id   Gene.Id  Score.d
1  1418126_at      6352 28.52578
2  1423477_at      <NA> 24.43532
3  1434193_at 100506144  6.22395
4  1434193_at      9204  6.22395
5 145119_a_at      2192 24.87866
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that uses the constructor for `data.frame`, using the "feature" that it silently recycles input vectors:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        apply(dat, 1, function(x) 
                         data.frame(Probe.ID=x['Probe.Id'], 
                                    Gene.Id=strsplit(x['Gene.Id'], '///'),
                                    Score.d=x['Score.d'],
                                    row.names=NULL
                                   )
             )
        )
##      Probe.ID   Gene.Id  Score.d
## 1  1418126_at      6352 28.52578
## 2 145119_a_at      2192 24.87866
## 3  1423477_at      <NA> 24.43532
## 4  1434193_at 100506144  6.22395
## 5  1434193_at      9204  6.22395
```